# How do I mount an EBS root volume to a windows instance in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

So basically, I created a large windows server for development, and then I created a micro windows server for production.  I set up everything how I wanted it on my development server, and then i unmounted the drives, and mounted them to my micro server.

Now I'm trying to get back into my large windows development server, and I'm getting the error.

```
Invalid value 'i-4896ce28' for instanceId. Instance does not have a volume attached at root (/dev/sda1)
```

this error pops up when I try to start my large windows server.  I've remounted the drives to the large development server, and I still get this message.

I'm not really sure what to do, I've read other posts and everyone is giving these almost like command line arguments and talking about other tools, and I really have no clue what any of that means, or where I even have an option to enter any commands without be logged into a specific instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure the EBS-drive has the name `/dev/sda1` in the EC2-Console.

Comment: It was confusing to me how they put on the botton of the attach device dialog that windows devices should be xvdg-xvdh..I wasn't aware I could just type in /dev/sda1.   Thanks alot.

Comment: I've been there to; wouldn't know it otherwise ;)

Comment: In my case I had to enter "/dev/xvda" in the input field as "/dev/sda1" kept leading to the same error message. Using Debian Wheezy image.

Comment: What a strange behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can try /dev/xvda. When you attach a volume to the instance -> select the particular instance then enter /dev/xvda for the mount point.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all of your volumes are detached before re-attaching. In my case I had a volume attached to an earlier snapshot. Once i detached that I was allowed to attach my new volume.

Answer (score 0):

Under volumes > 'Detach volume' and then 'Attach Volume' and in the device field type the correct path. For example you might need to type: /dev/sda

Comment: +1 this actually worked for me, It boot up without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no leading space in '/dev/sda'

For some reason copying text out of the aws console often attaches a space in front of the string. A very annoying side effect that had me spinning my wheels for 15 minutes trying to get the primary drive on my production server remounted. I tried all of these solutions before figuring that out.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all this I finally fixed it by using `/dev/sda1`

The error being it seemed you can only input `/dev/sdf` up to `/dev/sdp`

But it used `/dev/sda1` correctly.

For the steps:

1. Note down the device name in error while starting the EC2 instance.
2. Detach the currently connected Volume with EC2
3. Attach volume to EC2

   Try to attached same volume to EC2 instance. However make sure that you are not using default “Device” such as “/dev/sdf” as below while attaching volume to EC2 instance.
4. Start EC2 instance

taken from [linuxroutes](https://linuxroutes.com/how-to-resolve-instance-does-not-have-a-volume-attached-at-root-dev-sda1-error/)